# First HTTP Request called from didReceiveRemoteNotification always fails

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I receive a simple remote notification and handle it like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let notificationObject = JSON(userInfo)

    if notificationObject["type"] == "friendRequest" {
        let tab = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        tab.selectedIndex = 1
    }
}
```

When opened, the push notification presents a ViewController that manages a subclassed `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`.

The `UITableViewCell` makes a network call for each cell to Google API as follows:

```
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=\(isbn)&fields=items(volumeInfo(imageLinks(thumbnail),industryIdentifiers))&key=\(GOOGLE_BOOKS_API_KEY)"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).response { response in
        print(response)
```

The calls for each cell succeed except for the first one, which gives me:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost.
```

Are there any iOS limitations/delays/interference for network calls on launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that sometimes you need to make little delay before performing certain things that fail, in case you execute them immediately.

Before calling a method, that starts building a `UITableView` and corresponding cells, wrap the method call into `dispatch_after` block, with delay of 0.1 seconds, which should be sufficient.

This should solve your problem with the first cell. In case this helps, you can experiment with delay, trying to make it even shorter.